# Objects's global variable

Tags: javascript

The problem is with object's variable:

> this.timer

it's not "global", so when I click the stop button the  value of the variable is wrong.
If I declare a global variable MyObject (loke var mytimer;) and use it instead this.timer, it works.

This is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">               
            var MyObject = {

                init: function(){
                    this.timer = 0;
                    document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function(){
                        MyObject.RunIt();
                    };
                    document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = function(){
                        clearInterval(this.timer);
                    };

                },

                RunIt: function(){
                    var x=0;
                    this.timer = setInterval(function(){
                x++;
                        document.getElementById("spn").innerHTML=x;
                    }, 1000);

                }

            };


        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="MyObject.init();">
        <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Run"/>
        <input type="button" id="btn2" value="Stop"/>
        <span id="spn"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "When I do it the wrong way it doesn't work"? I don't get what you're asking here...

Comment: I asked, why I don't get the real value of this.timer when I click the stop button.

Comment: Incidentally, you have a problem if you click ‘stop’ when it's already stopped, or ‘start’ when it's already started. I suggest setting `this.timer` to `null` initially and on stop, then testing `this.timer!==null` before trying to clear the interval, and also stopping the existing timer before starting a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this: when you set "onclick" to a function call like that, there's no object reference in the call. The browser calls your function to do the "clearInterval", but "this" is not pointing to your object - in fact, it's pointing at the button element itself.

Here's one way to work around the problem:

```
var self = this;
document.getElementById('btn2').onclick = function() {
  clearInterval(self.timer);
};
```

I know that question-askers on Stackoverflow get annoyed sometimes when people urge them to investigate jQuery or some other modern Javascript framework, but it's simply a better way to do things.

Comment: @Pointy: Regarding your last sentence, that's just your opinion. There are plenty of situations where I think it's preferable not to use one of the big JavaScript libraries.

Comment: about jquery maybe you're right, but If i wanted jquery I would added the necessary tag...

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem in writing javascript code; the **Scope**.

in an **.onclick** method on an element, the **scope** (this) is the element itself not the class you are in (MyObject).

i use this/that method; like below:

```
            init: function(){
                this.timer = 0;
                document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function(){
                    MyObject.RunIt();
                };

                var that = this;
                document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = function(){
                    /** 
                        Here i use 'that' instead of 'this';
                        because 'this' is the button element
                    */
                    clearInterval(that.timer);
                };

            },
```

Answer (score -1):

<strike>You can access an object through `this` only if the object was created by `new`.</strike>

The `this` in your code refers to the `window` object. In the event handlers it refers to the respective HTML element.

[Read a detailled explanation.](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)

<strike>Your MyObject declaration is an object, but lets say that it is not an object instance. There is a difference in JS.</strike>

Object instance example:

```
        function MyClass() {
                this.timer = 0;

                this.RunIt = function() {
                        var x=0;
                        this.timer = setInterval(function(){
                                x++;
                                document.getElementById("spn").innerHTML=x;
                        }, 1000);
                };

                var me = this; // alias to current "this"

                document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function(){
                    // "this" refers to btn1, use me
                    me.RunIt();
                };
                document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = function(){
                    // "this" refers to btn2, use me
                    clearInterval(me.timer);
                };
        }

        var MyObject = new MyClass();
```

Note, that there are many different ways to construct objects in JavaScript.

**EDIT**: it contains another bug: the event handler functions will be executed as members of the HTML element. So `this` in the handlers refers to the HTML element, not to your object.

**EDIT**: fixed the code

**EDIT**: Bad day, don't listen to me ;-)

Comment: Is there a workaround using the object declaration that I used?

Comment: mariki: you can put timer into your MyObject declaration, e.g. `var MyObject = { timer:0, ... }`. But the you always have to reference it through MyObject.timer - even in RunIt and the other two functions.

Comment: @frunsi again, that is simply not correct. There are ways of making it work the way he wants it to.

Comment: Pointy: it IS hardly correct, with a subtle difference: the `this` in the OPs code refers to the `window` object. So, yes, a `this` is available everywhere, but it does not refer to `MyObject`.

Comment: @frunsi I suggest you do some reading. It is entirely possible to arrange for the callback to work the way he wants, with the "this" pointer pointing at his object. (Also, the "this" in the original question will NOT refer to the "window" object, it'll refer to the button.)